# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" over list

Tags: python

I am wondering whether someone can help me with this mystery.
When I run my program it shows the error.

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I have tested that the variable that I am trying to iterate is a list however it still says that it is invalid and shows the same error.

My code it meant to print a symmetrical triangle of asterisks:

```
def iterat(num):
    for x in num:
        yield x

number=int(input("Enter Positive Number: "))

stars = list(range(number))
print(type(stars))
spaces = stars.reverse()
yeildStar = iterat(stars)
yeildSpace = iterat(spaces)

for star,space in zip(yeildStar,yeildSpace):
    print(" "*(space)+"*"*((star*2)-1))
```

Thank you very much. Sorry for the bad variable names

EDIT; Thank you for your help.

```
spaces = reversed(stars)
```

Worked perfectly

Comment: Something went wrong with your code indentation. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
spaces = stars.reverse()
```

`reverse`, like `append`, operates in-place and returns nil. To return a new list you need to do:

```
spaces = list(reversed(stars))
```

I must say though, I don't understand the point of your `iterat` generator. If you left spaces and stars as generators in the first place, you wouldn't need it at all:

```
stars = range(number)
spaces = reversed(stars)
for star,space in zip(stars, spaces):
    print(" "*(space-1)+"*"*((star*2)-1))
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is in the line

```
spaces = stars.reverse()
```

The return value of the list function `reverse()` is not the reversed list, but `None`, because the reversal is done in-place.

Use this line instead:

```
spaces = stars[::-1]
```

This returns a list with the reversed values of `stars`.